# Does ObjectAnimator drain bettery

Tags: android, objectanimator, batterylevel

I am using ObjectAnimator to create an Animation in the background of my text.I have a frameLayout containing 10  views which uses ObjectAnimator to create a random animation. This frameLayout is used as background to a text view.

I observed that after creating this background using ObjectAnimator the battery of my device has started draining fast.
I could not find any references where someone has faced similar problem.

Does ObjectAnimator cause battery drain if run continuously ? If yes, what could be the way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it does, but to what extent depends on the device and the battery itself.

**Proof of the Above Statement**

> ObjectAnimator and other animations doesn't work when battery saver mode is **ON**

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if it is necessary to call pause/resume ObjectAnimator when the activity is getting puased/resumed or it is done implicitly ?

Comment: AFAIK , you gotta do that explicitly!